# c# - Session Expired in selenium IE webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, session-timeout

I have a secured site from which I need to scrape data from some particular pages. The page should be opened strictly on IE. I opened the login page from selenium and pass the handle to the webdriver. Then the user surfs various pages and pop ups of that website. A timer runs and it is checked whether a particular page is opened or not. That is being checked with following code.

```
  var windowIterator = driver.WindowHandles;
  foreach (var windowHandle in windowIterator)
  {
     popup = driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowHandle);
     if (popup.Title == PageTitle) //PageTitle is string value and is saved in App Config
     {
        doWork = true; //Scraping would be started on this page
        break;
     }
  }
```

It is working perfectly for other sites in testing environment. In live environment the pop page is displaying with the session expired message and asking for user credentials. Once that is given then it is working fine. The architecture of the website that is being scraped is unknown to me.

Could any body tell me why this is happening and what is the way out.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly its takes too much of the time to scrap the data before page will be updated/changed.

I believe site give to your browser one-session-cookes. Check all of cookies that site gaves you. Possibly this can be resolved by cookies edit via selenium. If not -- you can refresh the page in smaller than life time of cookies and show to the server that "user is here" =)